# setInterval to reload page google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have code background js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: "setInterval(function(){alert('test')}, 2000)"
    });
});

var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Auto Refresh",
    "contexts": ["page"]
});​
```

It works, each 2 seconds it have a alert box "test";

But I replace alert('test') by location.reload:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: "setInterval(function(){location.reload()}, 2000)"
    });
});

var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Auto Refresh",
    "contexts": ["page"]
});​
```

It only have 1 refresh for the first time and don't continue to refresh. Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a page is refreshed, the `setInterval` handle will be gone, so it will not work as you expected.

A solution is to do `setInterval` inside your extension:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    setInterval(function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            code: "location.reload()"
        });
    }, 2000);
});

var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Auto Refresh",
    "contexts": ["page"]
});​
```

As I acknowledge that you want to refresh only the current page, I added `tab.index` as the first parameter to `chrome.tabs.executeScript` so that only the current page is being refreshed.

**Beware that** the user may choose the option more than once, so you may need to check if it is the case or remove the context menu item. Also when the tab is closed you will need to call `clearInterval`, or else you will cause a lot of problems. These are left for you to practice.

Comment: Hi Alvin, thank you but your solution will make user selected tab was refreshed, or when I add a new tab, it also was refreshed. I want only 1 tab is refreshed. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Alvin, what is tab.index? you mean tab.id? No I don't want to refresh current page, I want to refresh specific page, when I select a page, I click refresh on contextmenu, and this page will be refresh forever even I add a new tabs or select other tabs.

Comment: @DarkLight I don't see the difference between the current page and what you called "specific page"?

Comment: That mean, when I have a page A, I clicked on "Refresh" context menu, page A will be refreshed. When I add new page B, page A still refresh and page B is not refreshed

Comment: @DarkLight That's why I say there is no differences. You haven't even tried my code.

Comment: Hi Alvin, I tried your code, your code will refresh active page/current page, for example, when I select B page, your code will refresh B page, when I select C page, it will refresh C page. But I want to refresh A page, even I select any page, B, C, D or ..... any.

Answer (score 0):

@Alvin,

Base on your answer, I have find out solution to solve it:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var tabID;
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tabID = tab.id;
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, {
            code: "location.reload()"
        });
    }, 2000);
});
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Auto Refresh",
    "contexts": ["page"]
});
```

I added chrome.tabs.getSelected to save tab.id, and this solution is satisfied me :D